# Embedding html table in email

Tags: html, email

I am trying to embed the html table in to email I am sending from one the application I am building below is what I am trying

```
<table width="400" style="border:1px solid #333">
  <tr> 
     <th>Isolate Lots</th>
     <th>Identification</th>
  </tr>  
  #foreach( $sample in $SAMPLES)
  #if($EXPSAMPLES[$foreach.index].getData("jax_trait_isolateIdentification") !="Unidentified")  
  <tr>
  <td>$LOTS[$foreach.index].name </td>
  <td>$EXPSAMPLES[$foreach.index].getData("jax_trait_isolateIdentification") 
  </td>
  </tr>
  #end #end
 </table>
```

The table in the email looks like this
[image]

How can I put everything in the Cell inside the table and align them.

After edit

[image]

Comment: Before integrating with actual php code, create table html with sample and test. So that you can see how it is coming in mail. Once design is corrected,  add your logic to the html. Just a suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set `style="vertical-align: middle"` for each cell (since `valign="middle"` is obsolete).

```html
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 400px">
  <tr>
    <th style="border: 1px solid  #333; vertical-align: middle">Isolate Lots</th>
    <th style="border: 1px solid  #333; vertical-align: middle">Identification</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid  #333; vertical-align: middle">name</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid  #333; vertical-align: middle">jax_trait_isolateIdentification</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Upd: added borders

Comment: It still puts everything inside the table not the cells

Comment: Thanks it works but still can you look at the question I have added the table how it looks now. Not aligned especially the second column

Comment: It seems to me the problem is in the generated content of cells. Because by default cells have `vertical-align: middle`, you don't have to do anything special. Maybe PHP generates some unexpected white-spaces or line-breaks?..

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify what kind of alignment you mean, so here's my suggestion in case you want them centered, just added a 'align="center"' style to the cells.

```
<table width="400" style="border:1px solid #333">
  <tr> 
     <th align="center">Isolate Lots</th>
     <th align="center">Identification</th>
  </tr>  
  #foreach( $sample in $SAMPLES)
  #if($EXPSAMPLES[$foreach.index].getData("jax_trait_isolateIdentification") !="Unidentified")
  <tr>
  <td align="center">$LOTS[$foreach.index].name</td>
  <td align="center">$EXPSAMPLES[$foreach.index].getData("jax_trait_isolateIdentification")
  </td>
  </tr>
#end #end
 </table>
```

Comment: It still puts everything inside the table not the cells

Answer (score 0):

well your code is correct maybe u should try this
i just change the style of your table
hope it works. enter code here

```
<table width="400" border='1px' style='text-align:center'>
  <tr> 
     <th>Isolate Lots</th>
     <th>Identification</th>
  </tr>  
  #foreach( $sample in $SAMPLES)
  #if($EXPSAMPLES[$foreach.index].getData("jax_trait_isolateIdentification") !="Unidentified")  
  <tr>
  <td>$LOTS[$foreach.index].name </td>
  <td>$EXPSAMPLES[$foreach.index].getData("jax_trait_isolateIdentification") 
  </td>
  </tr>
  #end #end
 </table>
```